# use two ng-model with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I wrote this code

```
<label><input ng-model="filter['category']['auto']" value="auto" type="checkbox" name="category">Auto</label>
<label><input ng-model="filter['category']['music']" value="music" type="checkbox" name="category">Music</label>
```

in the controller

```
$scope.filter = {};
```

And I always filter the content with the filer. Every thing is working fine. But I want to use radio instead of checkbox to allow the selection of only one category. I tried this code

```
<label><input ng-model="filter['category'][type]" value="auto" type="radio" name="category" ng-change="type='auto'>Auto</label>
<label><input ng-model="filter['category'][type]" value="music" type="radio" name="category" ng-change="type='music'">Music</label>
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use radio buttons the ngModel should be the same for both inputs. Then there is no need for ngChange.

```
<label><input ng-model="filter['category']" value="auto" type="radio" name="category">Auto</label>
<label><input ng-model="filter['category']" value="music" type="radio" name="category">Music</label>
```

With this your `filter` object looks like

```
{ category: 'auto' }
```

or

```
 { category: 'music' }
```

With your original code you'd end up with

```
{ category: { auto: 'auto', music: 'music' }
```

assuming that category is an object. If its not you likely are getting an error.

Comment: But I want to get/set the value in the controller

Comment: If you are trying to set the value of the "category" property, the code in my answer will do that. If that's not the value you are trying to get/set then I don't have a good understanding of your model, but you still should not need to use ngChange on an input - set the model properly in the ngModel attribute and clicking the radio button will set the value.

Answer (score 0):

In the future I would definitely do more to explain what errors you were getting and not just say 'it's not working'.

However, you are missing a closing " in your auto label tag.

```
<label><input ng-model="filter['category']['type']" value="auto" type="radio" name="category" ng-change="type='auto'">Auto</label>
```

EDIT: added the 'type' string from the other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><input ng-model="filter['category']" value="auto" type="radio" name="category" ng-change="type='auto'">Auto</label>
<label><input ng-model="filter['category']" value="music" type="radio" name="category" ng-change="type='music'">Music</label>
```

This should work as [shown here](http://jsbin.com/dosujuzuso/)